# why rdbms cant store unstructured data?and why nosql databases can?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, rdbms, nosql

I have read that one of the differences between rdbms and nosql databases is storing unstructured data,I know each nosql database has its own architecture and algorithms,but I want to know why rdbms cant store unstructured data?

and why nosql databases can do that,I will be really thankful if you show me a simple example so that I can understand how nosql databases do that,and what makes rdbms unable to store unstructured data.

Comment: Dunno who said that but SQL techs can store structured data it is just that most people don't know about it because all they see if the default flat structure of a table

Comment: Not all No-SQL databases are unstructured.

Comment: Oh whoops read the question the wrong way round

Answer (score 2):

Relational databases are based on [Edgar F. Codd's relational data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) which assumes strictly structured data. The whole SQL language is constructed around this model and the databases which implement it are optimized for working that way.

But in the past few years, there were attempts to add features to SQL which allow to work with unstructured data, like the [SQL/XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML) extension which allows to store XML documents in fields of SQL tables and query their document-trees transparently.

Document-oriented databases like MongoDB or CouchDB, on the other hand, were designed from the start to work with unstructured data and their query languages were designed around this concept, so when working with unstructured data they are usually much faster and more convenient to use.

Comment: but I want an example to see how unstructured data will be stored and manipulated in nosql databases,please.

Comment: @NikooNam *which* NoSQL database? They all do it differently. And they all have extensive documentation with plenty of examles which you can easily find with a search engine of your choice.

Comment: @NikooNam unstructured simply means no schema, look it up if you need to

Answer (score 0):

I read this question totally wrong and thought about the problem totally wrong at first (multiple locale definitions of "structured") so ignore my comments, however, MongoDB does actually store structured data. The Wikipedia definition (which may I say seems to differ across the internet in itself) is that ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_data ):

> Unstructured Data (or unstructured information) refers to information that either does not have a pre-defined data model or is not organized in a pre-defined manner.

But that is untrue for MongoDB since it actually does have one:

```
{
    _id:{}
}
```

Since the `_id` is always required, as such it has been more accurately said by MongoDB users recently that MongoDB has a "flexible" schema and not nessecarily schemaless which is why most people say it stores unstructured data.

So yes, it does kind of store unstructured data but not totally...

Comment: That's an interesting point of view, but I think it doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @Philipp True it doesn't, though I thought it was quite interesting too so I thought I'd place it

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, NOSQL data stores are hierarchical, variable length, highly distributed file based systems with eventual consistency. The schema is embedded in the data (or in the code but NOSQLs are not schemaless), the columns can vary from one instance to the next even in the same structure, and the size of the columns is not fixed.